# Overwriting Elements in Linq to XML

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

So I have this XML file that I generate, it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Members xmlns="urn:lst-emp:emp">
  <Member xmlns="">
    <!--Info for Member TESTER-->
    <AccountName>Test Name</AccountName>
    <AccountNumber>Test Number</AccountNumber>
    <AccountBalance>Test Balance</AccountBalance>
  </Member>
  <Member xmlns="">
    <!--Info for Member Jeff Reed-->
    <AccountName>Jeff Reed</AccountName>
    <AccountNumber>5929</AccountNumber>
    <AccountBalance>9223.01</AccountBalance>
  </Member>
</Members>
```

And I can successfully target parts of an Element with

```
XElement xelement = XElement.Load(Application.LocalUserAppDataPath + "\\members.xml");
IEnumerable<XElement> members = xelement.Elements();
members.Where(x => x.Element("AccountName").Value == memberName).Select(x => x.Element("AccountNumber").Value).Single();
```

and assign it to a variable or something, but after I alter this variable, how can I overwrite it back into the Element on my XML file?
I've tried the below with no prevail. Any other ideas?

```
internal static void overwriteAccountBalance(string memberName, string newBalance)
    {
        XElement xelement = XElement.Load(Application.LocalUserAppDataPath + "\\members.xml");
        IEnumerable<XElement> members = xelement.Elements();
        members.Where(x => x.Element("AccountName").Value == memberName).Select(x => x.Element("AccountBalance").Value = newBalance);
        xelement.Save(Application.LocalUserAppDataPath + "\\members.xml");
    }
```

Comment: What is your need? Why you need to again over write your previous value after performing replace operation? If you need to overwrite again then perform same operation after completing first operation...But in reversal mode... newBalance in where condition and memberName in replace value...

Comment: As you can see in the XML above, I can get the "AccountBalance", and even assign it to a variable using
---
string accountBalance = members.Where(x => x.Element("AccountName").Value == memberName).Select(x => x.Element("AccountBalance").Value).Single();
----
but then I can't replace the value in the XML after I am done altering it.

Comment: Here you Save your file so when you try to replace then again need to save file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select the Element, then set the value. Like so:

```
XElement xelement = XElement.Load("C:\\members.xml");
IEnumerable<XElement> members = xelement.Elements();
members.First(x => x.Element("AccountName").Value == memberName).Element("AccountBalance").Value = newBalance;
xelement.Save("C:\\members.xml");
```

So this is saying, get me the first member Element that has an AccountName element equal to memberName, and *then* set it's AccountBalance element to the newBalance.

Note, this doesn't take into account the possibility of nulls or no element with the specified name...

Answer (score 1):

LINQ is Lazy-Evaluated(or Deferred Executed, see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb943859.aspx)), therefore the select statement in your last example will never be executed.  To force the LINQ query to evaluate, use a method that returns the data that is not in the literal IEnumerable form(like ToArray(), First(), Single(), ToList(), ect.).

```
internal static void overwriteAccountBalance(string memberName, string newBalance)
{
    XElement xelement = XElement.Load(Application.LocalUserAppDataPath + "\\members.xml");
    IEnumerable<XElement> members = xelement.Elements();

    //ToArray() forces the query to evaluate
    members.Where(x => x.Element("AccountName").Value == memberName).Select(x => x.Element("AccountBalance").Value = newBalance).ToArray();
    xelement.Save(Application.LocalUserAppDataPath + "\\members.xml");
}
```

Storing the result and evaluating it in a `foreach` loop causes it to execute as well.

```
internal static void overwriteAccountBalance(string memberName, string newBalance)
{
    XElement xelement = XElement.Load(Application.LocalUserAppDataPath + "\\members.xml");
    IEnumerable<XElement> members = xelement.Elements();

    //Evaluate part of the query and do the rest yourself
    foreach(XElement member in members.Where(x => x.Element("AccountName").Value == memberName))
    {
        XElement accountBalance = member.Element("AccountBalance");
        if(accountBalance != null)
        {
             accountBalance.Value = newBalance;
        }
    }
    xelement.Save(Application.LocalUserAppDataPath + "\\members.xml");
}
```

I prefer the second because it allows you to easily provide better condition handling(like checking for `null`)

Comment: +1 for pointing out that it works if the linq statement is evaluated.